# "Old Work" electrical box: should it be screwed into the stud?

Tags: electrical, junction-box, old-work

I'm interested in replacing an existing outlet (in a wall that's finished with drywall) with a two-gang duplex (four outlets total), using an "old work" box.  This box is located in the garage, so I'd like it to be sturdy.

### Is it considered good practice to screw the box sideways into the stud?

[image: Photo and diagram of old work 2-gang box]

It appears from another forum that this might violate electrical codes.
In the US, where I am:

> NEC 314.23.  Supports.
> (B) Structural Mounting.
> (1) Nails and Screws. Nails and screws, where used as a
> fastening means, shall be attached by using brackets on the
> **outside of the enclosure, or they shall pass through the
> interior within 6 mm (1/4 in.) of the back or ends of the
> enclosure. Screws shall not be permitted** to pass through the
> box unless exposed threads in the box are protected using
> approved means to avoid abrasion of conductor insulation.

If so, is there a better way to support **old work** boxes than just relying on the drywall tabs?

Comment: In general, if you can screw into the stud, you don't use an old work box. In other general, blue plastic boxes - ugh. When I was an ignorant teenager, sure. Now, no. Steel is good.

Comment: Regardless of plastic or steel,  I thought "new work" boxes are set up so that the nails/screws are **outside the box (either above or below)**.   I don't have access to above or below, only "inside" the box.

Comment: If you want to talk about electrical code, you have to talk about where you live.  In Canada boxes come with holes to screw to studs, both inside and outside the box.  The way this is worded "pass through" the box makes me think of an old installation style where long nails or screws were driven right through the box and into the stud, which is a huge pain to work around, but also easier to remove for rework than external fasteners.  Arguably the wall you want to drill through is an end of the enclosure, so the head of a fully driven screw would be within 6mm of it.  Not my code though.

Comment: Your explanation for the intent of "pass through" makes sense.   (Pass ***all the way***, through both walls, starting the outside.)  I was interpreting "pass through" as including the diagram above.

Comment: The purpose/advantage of an old work box is that you use it where there is no stud to attach to. The tabs bind it to the drywall.  **If you use the tabs then you do not need to screw it to a stud**.  IF you have a stud to attach to then you would use the box that jack recommends in his answer.

Comment: @Ecnerwal: Isn't steel a problematic material for electric juncture box enclosures? I mean, being conductive and all? Sure, blue is not the fashion statement I would make, but all the boxes I see are plastic, and in rare cases of very old ones - wood.

Comment: No, it's not. Live wires should not be touching the box, if the box is being used correctly. And a grounded steel box will contain a fire that will burn through a plastic box.

Comment: @KH Yes, you are correct - this is exactly what it's talking about.  Smooth shank nails were awkward to work around, but sharp threads on wood screws pose a real risk to the wiring so it's a no-no added to code to correct for old-timers using screws in the same way they used to use nails.

Comment: I installed a number of double- and triple-gang boxes like that when we initially updated the wiring in our house. I've had no problems with either outlets or switches feeling wobbly. Of course, I've got plaster & lath walls, so it's stiffer than just drywall, but, depending on exactly where the box hits, there's a fair bit of play available if it's just plaster supporting the ears. I really haven't had any issue even with those boxes. If you were to have any wobble, it would most likely be on the end away from the stud anyway, and your screws wouldn't help that.

Comment: There's no issue with plastic boxes, ignore the vague FUD about them in the first comment.

Comment: @Ecnerwal plastic boxes aren't so bad.  I like metal but some countries prefer plastic.  Advantages and disadvantages.  Metal boxes are intended to contain flash, not fire, which plastic boxes can also do so although a larger hole in a metal box is acceptable for that purpose.  There isn't enough combustable and oxygen inside a plastic box to start a large enough fire and any fire hot enough to light fire resistant plastic has likely caught the surrounding house up too.

Comment: @einpoklum a metal box is no more problem than other non conducting metal parts in the house so long as it is properly grounded.  If a live wire is shorted to it, the low impedance of the ground causes a large current to flow and blow the breaker.  They're a little riskier in ungrounded 2 wire systems with metal boxes which do exist in North America.  If wiring can't be changed we use GFCIs to protect the circuit and shorting to the box does appear to trigger the GFCI at least some of the time.  That said, if it doesn't trigger the GFCI, all the exposed metal will be energised if not isolated.

Comment: A metal cover or the cover plate screw could be energised.  In some of these old systems a bootleg ground is used, meaning the components to be grounded are connected to neutral so if a hot wire shorts to them a large current flows and the breaker trips.  In this case however, if the neutral is broken between a device and the panel, all of the "grounded" parts are energised to line voltage through the loads.  In a modern system with proper grounding though, a metal box is safe and offers different advantages than a plastic one.  I mostly like plastic for low durability rain tight or in slab.

Comment: Even in slab though for wall and floor boxes I'd usually go with duct taped masonry boxes as it's easier to mount them rigidly to withstand the concrete pour and they are often vastly cheaper than a slab specialized plastic box that will do the same.  , especially in a wall where the concrete is falling 10 feet.  [Core line octagon and square boxes](https://www.walterswholesale.com/ipex-smb-h-15-pvc-round-slab-box-with-molded-connector--4--3-4-inch-hub-3-5-8-inch-kwikon-reg-7230) are plastic and great for mounting in ceilings, but their claim that connectors are concrete tight is laughable.

Comment: Duct tape every coupling and connector with core line,  You can buy boxes of duct tape for the cost of chipping out one pipe.

Comment: @KH: "non conducting metal"? Conductivity is part of the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal) of metal, isn't it?

Comment: @einpoklum in this case I refer to the intent of the use of the metal rather than its electrical properties.  It would be more proper to say "non-current carrying conductors" but that usually refers to intentional conductors like ground wires that only carry current during a fault, so in this case I went with "non conducting metal" to imply metal not used as an intentional conductor.  It's fair to say that "most metals are conductors" but usually when I refer to a conductor I mean intentional conductor.

Comment: Someone forgot to tell lead, tungsten, titanium, etc. that they aren't real metals because they are poor conductors! :-)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Junction boxes are not to have additional holes drilled into them for securing them to studs. The box you have shown can be used and mounted fairly secure if you take the time to cut the opening as small as possible so the box tabs have more drywall to support it.

A better solution is to get a box similar to the one below with side screws already included to be mounted to the stud. This is the same size as the old work box but allows you to screw directly into the stud.

[image]

***Southwire Smart Box 2-Gang Adjustable Depth Device Box #MSB2G***

Comment: JACK:  I'd forgotten about those, that's also a good option and a much faster install than my answer.   Still, though, I think my solution would result in a more rigid mount....the question then becomes, how important is a bit of flex vs. the additional time and effort of my solution.   Up to the OP.   +

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson  I think these are relatively new on the market as I don't remember seeing them when I was working. I recently used one for a utility outlet changing my dryer from three prong to four prong just to keep Harper happy  :-)  The box had very little flex and that was eliminated with the cover.  I have used your solution many times but added a few drywall screw so I didn't have to wait for the glue to dry. +1

Comment: Thanks JACK. That works too.  The only reason I suggested glue was to prevent the need of patching over additional screws in the drywall...which would be visible.   LOL regarding keeping Harp happy!  Take care.

Comment: In other words, get a new work box rather than an old work box...

Comment: @Jack this doesn't apply worldwide, so could you add the electrical code or jurisdiction it applies to?  I'm sorry you're not allowed to attach boxes this way.  Do you have to put up with non-beautiful non primary colored wire as well?

Comment: On second thought you may be referring only to plastic junction boxes as there are concerns about attaching them that don't apply to metal ones.

Comment: @KH  The NEC  doesn't allow the customer to drill extra holes in boxes to mount them. they don't want screw heads protruding where they might damage insulation.   We do have a rainbow selection of wire though. :-)

Comment: @Jack for an actual responsible electrician I see little problem with a few well thought out extra holes in a metal box, but I admit I have seen some homeowner crap with very foolishly placed screws.  Still glad to have the extra option though.

Comment: @KH  I agree, little problem until an inspector fails the job and you have to replace it.  Happened to me in my younger years... inspector was trying to make a point... it stuck...  EMT three way into box.

Comment: @Jack Yeah we don't have that rule though so I don't have to worry about the inspector problem, just the homeowner problem caused by the lack of a rule.  I had an inspector make me tear out a bunch of double stacked staples(correct size for stacking) and use single staples to strap the wire in a much more hazardous way.  I should have made him show me a rule for reference anyway because the staples packaging was marked for the use and I'd learned that way in electrical school, but whatever I just assumed it was a new rule and re-stapled the wires with singles.

Answer (score 17):

### No, and you'll crack the box if you try.

Plastic is not metal.  Plastic boxes are flimsy things.  They don't have any strength except where they have been gusseted specifically to have strength.

This means you cannot simply add mounting points *anywhere* on the box.  The box will simply crack there, either from the violence of a self-drilling screw, or the stress points from a drilled hole clamped by a tightened screw, or the physical strain of people wrestling plugs out of a stiff socket.

No, boxes of this type are made to be used *exactly one way*: placed in a drywall hole *exactly the size of the provided template*, and then clamp **to the drywall** using the ears on the outside and the swinging clamps on the inside.   You are required to use that box that way, or not at all.  NEC 110.3(B).

I quite agree "to the drywall" is a bad deal and will not withstand ordinary stresses of wrestling a 3-prong socket out of a new, quality (stiff) receptacle socket.  I'd find another way.

### Try steel

If you want to 'freestyle' mountings like this, it's time to move over to steel boxes.  Steel has the strength to allow you to drill holes where you please and use them for mounting screws.  Steel is also vastly superior for every purpose of a junction box (containing arc fires, not melting and letting a fire spread, causing loose or arcing wires to trip the breaker).

It even self-grounds switches and certain receptacles, so one less wire to wrestle.  Really, in a metal box you attach your cables' ground wires to the box first and push them all the way into the back of the box, and never touch them again.

For old work, you need to select a box that has internal cable clamps.  This will also have fewer knockouts which makes it easier to find hole locations.

Comment: Many (most?) plastic boxes are of a more flexible kind, and don't cracky that easily. Although I tend to use a drill bit intended for woodwork for drilling holes in plastic. Then a truss-head or pan-head screw, maybe even with a washer to spread out the pressure.

Comment: The most common j-boxes (read cheapest) are the soft plastic variety. My father-in-law loves to screw those to the joist and they take to it decently well. I would imagine the fiberglass hard shell variety would not fare so well.

Comment: The flexibility is part of the problem @einpoklum.  If you use improper attachment points that are not gusseted, the box will at the least flex and shift, meaning your box is moving around while you wrestle plugs in/out of a stiff socket.  That in turn can result in cracking at the stress points added through drilling.  Plastic, as a material, is simply not metal - and UL has not tested or approved these boxes for field modification.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica: Isn't "gussetting" for corners? Or do you mean some kind of reinforcement plating or extra plastic around the attachment point? Anyway, I'm just not used to seeing metal electric boxes.

Comment: I mean reinforcements.  I rarely deal with plastic boxes myself.

Comment: Its worth noting that in many areas the self grounding provided by the receptacles, although it will keep a plug tester happy, is not considered ground for some devices and the wire from ground screw to box should not be neglected.

Comment: @KH NEC goes into detail exactly when receptacles can self-ground without a ground wire.  Hard flush contact yoke to box will suffice, or a receptacle UL-listed for self-grounding due to a contact-brush feature to touch the mounting screw.

Comment: And you did even say "certain" receptacles, but in my experience, those receptacles are super rare and I wouldn't want someone to get the wrong idea.  The ones that don't self ground *appear* to self ground is the problem I see.  I'm not going to mess with art, but if it appeals to you, you could say "special" receptacles rather than "certain" receptacles.

Comment: @Harper, thank you for the suggestion to use a steel box and drill holes "where you please": does this mean that in your understanding, NEC 314.23 (quoted) — requiring screws to be 6mm off the back or sides — refers **only** to screws that pass all the way across the box (through two walls) and **does not prohibit** screws if they're mounted using **only** one sidewall of the box?

Answer (score 7):

When I've had to do this, here's how I did it:  Cut the new opening to size for the new box. Then cut 2 pieces of 1/2" plywood about 2" x 8" or so. Apply glue and slip them into the opening above and below with the edges aligned horizontally with the edge of the top and bottom respectively. Clamp in place until the glue dries. Then use a box with plaster ears (flanges) using them to screw into the sheetrock/plywood.  I'd mark the holes and pre-drill because if you bust out the plywood, you'll have a real mess on your hands!  It's a little time consuming, but turns out a great result.

Your other option of course is to simply cut out the sheetrock from one stud to the other, install a new work box and repair the sheet rock, but I don't think that's what you want to do.

BTW, just screwing inside the box to the stud will result in a lot of movement of the box when plugging in and unplugging cords.   Don't ask me how I know this!  Did it once, never again.

Answer (score 2):

Buy a better box if you want it to be sturdy. Partially because there's a shortage, I couldn't buy a 2-gang old work plastic blue box like the one you pictured in the question. Nearby, there was a much pricier [fiberglass box that came with metal tabs](https://www.homedepot.com/p/FiberglassBox-2-Gang-32-1-2-cu-in-Old-Work-Switch-or-Receptacle-Box-R9329-EWK/202536031).

[image: Fiberglass old work box]

Not only will that box grip anything, it doesn't warp at all. The next step up from there would be a metal box, but that might require clamps and other things to get the wire safely in (plus you need to bond metal boxes).

Comment: In some areas you can just buy metal old work boxes if you don't want plastic, which likely cost less than this super fancy fibreglass one I've never seen.  There are actually 3 different styles of metal old work box you can get where I live, 4 if you include F clips.  Here the plastic one costs a few cents more and isn't available in every store.  Having to ground metal boxes is more advantage than disadvantage as they come with 2 or more ground screws, each of which can fasten 2 ground wires, so you often don't need a wire nut or Wago and you get some free box volume as a result.

Answer (score 0):

had to resort to securing the side of the box when the damm plastic tab failed, crossed my finger and moved on.

my general concern with old work boxes is the habit of not securing a new conductor to a stud as required by code.
think of all the YouTube vids that show a new added conductor to  old work box (next to stud or in between studs).

Comment: Please [edit] this to clarify how it addresses the Question and remove the conversational commentary. Answers here are expected to stand alone and clearly address the asker's concerns. See the [tour] to find out more about how we operate differently from a discussion board.